# Extra promise at start and Extra promise at end

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

New at promises, so feel free to be verbose.

I am writing a function "extra_promises_at_start_and_end" that returns a promise to do something.

This function may know immediately that it will fail (ie: return a promise that is rejected).  Question 1: Is there something like Promise.give_me_a_rejected_promise(..) or do I have to create a promise and reject it just like my code does?

Similarly, my function "extra_promises_at_start_and_end" calls other functions that return promises. At the end of this async chaining of work, I need to some final processing.  Question 2a/2b: Since my function returns a promise, I need to create a promise to do this last bit of work. Is this correct that I need to create a promise and immediately accepted or reject it? Is there a Promise.give_me_a_rejected_promise(..).

My code works as expected, just feels like I am missing something, and so generating redundant code.

Code in question:

```
// this is the function that may have redundant code
// see question 1 and 2
function extra_promises_at_start_and_end() {
    // fake out some module scope variable that indicates if this call is allowed to proceed or not
    let ok_to_proceed = Math.random() > 0.5

    // this function "extra_promises_at_start_and_end returns" a promise, 
    // Question 1: I need to create a Promise just to reject it immediatly?
    if (!ok_to_proceed) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { reject("failed before starting anything") }) // feels wrong
    }

    // do 5 things in sequence
    return another_module_promise_to_do_something(1).then(() => {
        return another_module_promise_to_do_something(2)
    }).then(() => {
        return another_module_promise_to_do_something(3)
    }).then(() => {
        return another_module_promise_to_do_something(4)
    }).then(() => {
        return another_module_promise_to_do_something(5)
    }).then(() => {
        // need to do something after the above 5 tasks are done, 

        console.log("doing something after all 5 things are done")

        // this function "extra_promises_at_start_and_end" returns a promise, 
        // Question 2a: I need to create a promise just to resolve it immediatly?
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(); }) // feels wrong
        }).catch((id) => {
            // this function extra_promises_at_start_and_end returns a promise, 
            // Question 2b: I need to create one just to reject it immediatly?
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { reject(id); }) // feels wrong
        })
}
```

The caller of this code is expecting a promise.

```
// run the test
console.log("calling something that will return a promise to let me know when it's done");
extra_promises_at_start_and_end()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("done :)")
    }).catch((id) => { console.log("failed id = " + id) })
```

Finally, a stub for testing my function

```
// pretend this is a complex task (ie: not suitable for inlining)
// done by some other module
// it returns a promise
function another_module_promise_to_do_something(id) {
    console.log("starting " + id)

    let P = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("  inside promise " + id)

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (Math.random() > 0.1) {
                console.log("  finished " + id);
                resolve();
            } else {
                console.log("  failed " + id)
                reject(id);
            }
        }, Math.random() * 1000)
    })

    return P;
}
```

If this is the way it is supposed to be done, then let me know and I will stop searching for the correct way to use promises.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for for question 1: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject

Answer (score 0):

What I learned is:

- Promise.resolve(value) method returns a Promise object that is resolved with the given value.  So anyone calling my function can do a then on the response.
- Promise.reject(reason) method returns a Promise object that is rejected with the given reason. So any chaining will fail as needed.
- Any return value in then will get encapsulated in a promise.  Feels like this obscures the intent. So not using.

My new function is as follows:

```
function promise_something() {
    // fake out some module scope variable that indicates if this call is allowed to proceed or not
        let ok_to_proceed = Math.random() > 0.5



 if (!ok_to_proceed) {
        return Promise.reject("failed before starting anything") 
    }

    // do 5 things in sequence
    return another_module_promise_to_do_something(1).then(() => {
        return another_module_promise_to_do_something(2)
    }).then(() => {
        return another_module_promise_to_do_something(3)
    }).then(() => {
        return another_module_promise_to_do_something(4)
    }).then(() => {
        return another_module_promise_to_do_something(5)
    }).then(() => {
        // need to do something after the above 5 tasks are done, 

        console.log("doing something after all 5 things are done")

        return Promise.resolve()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `then()` and `catch()` functions of a `Promise` return a `Promise`.

Your last big chunk of code is indeed redundant. If you needed to do any processing after the 5th chained invocation of `then()`, you could just chain another `then()`.

Here's a more bare-bones version of your code to illustrate:

```js
const countFromOneToFive = () => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return Promise.reject("Cosmic radiation ruined your promises. Great.");
  }

  return Promise.resolve([])
    .then((countToFive) => {
      countToFive.push(1);
      return countToFive;
    })
    .then((countToFive) => {
      countToFive.push(2);
      return countToFive;
    })
    .then((countToFive) => {
      countToFive.push(3);
      return countToFive;
    })
    .then((countToFive) => {
      countToFive.push(4);
      return countToFive;
    })
    .then((countToFive) => {
      countToFive.push(5);
      return countToFive;
    });
};

countFromOneToFive()
  .then((countToFive) => {
    countToFive.forEach((number) => console.log(number));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error, "Curses!");
  });
```

You can use `Promise.reject()` to just return a rejected `Promise`. This is handled in the catch statement in the bottom.

You can do all of your processing with as many `then()` invocations as you want. You can simply return after your final `then()` to have a `Promise`. From there, treat it like any promise and append `then()`s and `catch()`s as you see fit.

Answer (score -1):

> 1: Is there something like Promise.give_me_a_rejected_promise(..) or do I have to create a promise and reject it just like my code does?

like `Promise.reject(err)`?

> // Question 2a: I need to create a promise just to resolve it immediatly?

The point where this is written in your code is inside a promise chain. You don't need to do anything at all (in that context), to return a resolved Promise, except maybe not `throw`ing.

This Promise will resolve to any value you return, except `undefined`. And if you return `undefined` *(explicitely or implicitely)*, this Promise will resolve to the last value before that, in the Promise chain.
Only if you need to *explicitely* resolve to `undefined` you'd have to `return Promise.resolve()`.

> // Question 2b: I need to create one just to reject it immediatly?

Still inside the Promise chain: Since a rejected value is like a thrown Error in sync code, all you need to do here is to `throw`.

But that is pointless in the context you asked. Why catching an Error, just to immediately throw the very same Error, without doing anything else in that catch-block.

So your code could be like

```
function extra_promises_at_start_and_end() {
    // fake out some module scope variable that indicates if this call is allowed to proceed or not
    let ok_to_proceed = Math.random() > 0.5

    if (!ok_to_proceed) {
        return Promise.reject("failed before starting anything");
    }

    // do 5 things in sequence
    return another_module_promise_to_do_something(1)
        .then(() => another_module_promise_to_do_something(2))
        .then(() => another_module_promise_to_do_something(3))
        .then(() => another_module_promise_to_do_something(4))
        .then(() => another_module_promise_to_do_something(5))
        .then(() => {
            // need to do something after the above 5 tasks are done, 

            console.log("doing something after all 5 things are done")

            return null; //so the previous value is no longer propagated by this Promise
        })
        //.catch(id => { throw id }) //is pointless.
}
```

> When you say "This Promise will resolve to any value you return". So returning new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve 100}).then .... blaw blaw blaw is the same as 100.then .. blaw blaw blaw ?

Not exactly. Inside a Promise chain, returning a plain value like `100` or a Promise that resolves to 100 *(like `return Promise.resolve(100)`)* is equivalent in result ...

```
var foo1 = somePromise.then(() => {
    //do something
    return 100
})
//is equivalent in result to
var foo2 = somePromise.then(() => {
    //do something
    return Promise.resolve(100);
})
//or to
var foo3 = somePromise.then(() => {
    //do something
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(100));
})
```

`foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3` are all promises that resolve to the value `100` after `somePromise` has finished. That's equivalent in result.

... but you can't call `then()` on a number.

```
//you can do
somePromise.then(() => {
    //do something
    return 100
}).then(...)

//or sometimes you want to do
somePromise.then((value) => {
   //usually because you need `value` inside `.then(...)`
    return somethingAsync().then(...)
})

//but you can NOT do 
somePromise.then(() => {
    //do something
    return 100.then(...)
})
```

Comment: @grabbag, not exactly. I've extended the Answer to explain that